# Remove mailto anchor from DisplayFor

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following model property:

```
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

When I use the displayfor:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EmailAddress)
```

it adds a 'mailto' anchor to the text. Is there anyway I can specify for it not to include this?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use one of the followings.

```
  @Model.EmailAddress
```

OR

```
  @Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
```